# Unable to start MYSQL server on wamp getting error Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver, mysql-error-1064

I am getting this error please help.

> ```
> [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
> [ERROR] Aborting
> ```

Comment: Please share more information about your problem.

Comment: Is this after a fresh install, or did it just happen after things used to work

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
`mysql`.`user`
```

not

```
`mysql.user`
```